# Creating new Drupal nodes based on created HTML output

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, dynamic-content

I have a module in Drupal 6 that parses an XML feed and creates HTML output.  Essentially, I have a long string of the HTML that should populate that page.  This is being done on a local server at the moment.

What I would like to do is take that output and create new nodes with it.  I've seen that, with the Feeds module, I can import content.  What I would like to do is have the following procedure:

1. Run script (cron or user-instigated)
2. Generate HTML content and put it to some sort of local file
3. Import that content with a module on my production server (Feeds or otherwise)

As I mentioned, my HTML content is currently exactly as I want it.  However, it needs to become static nodes (for posterity's sake).  I can programmatically generate the HTML for each node, however I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be.

Comment: voting to close as this question isn't relevant to my problem anymore (and i have no experience with the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply created Drupal nodes programmatically.  Turned out to be easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Import HTML](http://drupal.org/project/import_html) module.

Comment: Does this module import HTML directly without any need for formatting?  I literally have the exact HTML I want locally that just needs to be pushed to production.